# Python: Create a microservice that uses a multiprocess worker pool to answer queries

Tags: python, parallel-processing, microservices, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I have a Python class, named `Brish`. This class takes time to initialize, and can answer queries ala `brish.z("QUERY HERE")`. I want to create a microservice for my local machine that accepts queries with a REST HTTP API, and uses load-balancing of a worker pool (with a fixed capacity of, say, 4 Brish instances) to answer these queries. I want these workers to be multiprocess, so that they can take full advantage of the CPU cores available. What libraries/design patterns should I use?

I have worked with Scala's Akka, and I am familiar with the actor model. I have taken a look at `multiprocessing.Pool`, `Ray`, `Pykka`, and `aioprocessing`, but after the ~2 hours I have spent looking at their docs, I am still confused which of them is the tool I need.

PS: The REST HTTP API can be replaced with any API that I can easily use from bash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concurrent.futures` which will allow you to create a pool of processes. Number of processes can be set to either the number of cores available or as many as you want.

Here is an amazing [video](https://youtu.be/fKl2JW_qrso?t=1059) which explains how to use this module.

I'd suggest you to watch the above video first, then read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer myself, though I don't know how buggy it is.

```
from typing import Optional

from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
app = FastAPI()


import time
import brish
brishes = [brish.Brish() for i in range(4)]

@app.get("/zsh/")
def cmd_zsh(cmd: str, verbose: Optional[int] = 0):
    while len(brishes) <= 0:
        time.sleep(1)
    myBrish = brishes.pop()
    res = myBrish.z(cmd)
    brishes.append(myBrish)
    if verbose == 0:
        return Response(content=res.outerr, media_type="text/plain")
    else:
        return {"cmd": cmd, "brishes": len(brishes), "out": res.out, "err": res.err, "retcode": res.retcode}
```